# Getting grand children of an instance

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have associations set up so that a Category has many Posts and each Post has many Comments:

`Category` → `Post` → `Comment`

Having an instance of `Category`, how do one get all `comments`?

I've tried this:

```
const posts = await category.getPosts()
const comments = await posts.map(post => post.getComments())
```

But the returned `comments` is only an array of `Promises`:

```
[ Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined },
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

This is what happening in your case. posts.map retruns an array which is not promise and hence await is resolving with the array of promises.

```
const posts = await category.getPosts()
const comments = await posts.map(post => post.getComments())
```

In the above logic posts.map is returning an array but not a promise. so to make it work you need to wrap that map in a Promise.all.

```
const posts = await category.getPosts()
const comments = await Promise.all(posts.map(post => post.getComments()))
```

Now when we print comments it will display array of the responses from all the resolved promises.